Why is the order of the incoming corners different between apriltag and aruco markers in opencv?
I am using opencv/4.9.0 and the aruco detector. My code look like this:

const auto image = cv::imread('tagfile.png', IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

const auto family = cv::aruco::PredefinedDictionaryType::<family>;
cv::aruco::ArucoDetector detector {cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(family)};
auto ids = std::vector<int>{};
auto markers = std::vector<std::vector<::cv::Point2f>>{};

detector.detectMarkers(image, markers, ids);

for (const auto& marker : markers) {
   const auto top_left = marker[0];
   const auto top_right = marker[1];
   const auto bottom_right = marker[2];
   const auto bottom_left = marker[3];

   std::cout << "top_left: " << top_left << std::endl;
   std::cout << "top right: " << top_right << std::endl;
   std::cout << "bottom right: " << bottom_right << std::endl;
   std::cout << "bottom left: " << bottom_left << std::endl;
}



I am using the following images as input:
DICT_6X6_1000:

and
DICT_APRILTAG_25h9:

The expected corner order is as in the documentation described top left, top right, bottom right and bottom left.
But for the apriltag, I got the following order: Bottom right, bottom left, top left and top right.
It seems that the apriltag pattern is rotated around the z axes with 180 degree. ArUco marker is the order correct. So my question is here, feature or bug of opencv.

what if aruco arranges the modules (pixels) one way and apriltag does it another way (rotated in some way)? what if they use entirely different mechanisms for encoding the identification number?

Could be, but the api should handle this(reordering the corners) , and return the order as mention in the documentation

I believe it does? which is why you get those corners in different orders, depending on how that picture (they're the same picture) is interpreted?
